# UICollectionView gets resized inside of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a subclassed `UICollectionViewController` that I use in multiple places in an app. When adding it straight onto a view, it looks correct (horizontal alignment, vertical scrolling), like so:

```
self.activityFeed = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"activityFeed"];
self.activityFeed.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 76, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
[self.view addSubview:self.activityFeed.view];
```

[image]

**However**, when adding it to a `UIScrollView`, the alignment changes for some reason, like so:

```
self.activityFeed = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"activityFeed"];
self.activityFeed.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
[self.scrollContentView addSubview:self.activityFeed.view];
// scrollContentView is a view that holds all of my subviews in the scrollview
// also, activityFeed.view has no autolayout constraints attached
```

[image]

I know that constraints work a lot different inside of scroll views, is there anything that I need to do differently in order to make my collection view look the same way as it does in the first image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, it's as simple as setting ,No need to take separate scrollview.

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES
```

Comment: Having a separate scroll view is something irrelevant to this question. That scroll view is necessary for other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Set scroll direction to horizontal in storyboard attribute pane.

Comment: This is already set to be horizontal, as it is the same storyboard controller that is being used for the first example, which is working.